# MySQL SELECT substring? or regex?

Tags: regex, substring

I have a column that stores a 9 digit number.

I'd like to select data where the number starts with 4 zeros - followed by a non-zero number as the 5th character :
i.e. 000038652
something like :
....
    WHERE SUBSTRING(num_column,0,4) = '[0-0]'
or :
    WHERE num_column REGEXP  '^[0-9]{4}$'

Comment: both are incorrect

Comment: Is it a numeric, or varchar on the database?

Comment: Just use `where num_column like '0000%'`.

Comment: It's a varchar actually. Phylogenesis - didn't think of this one!!! I'll give it a go. Thx. But - I need to know that the 5th character is not a zero as well

Comment: `where num_column like '0000%' and num_column not like '____0%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
WHERE num_column REGEXP '^[0]{4}[1-9][0-9]{4}$'
```

This will match records as follows:

`^[0]{4}`: Begins with four zeros

`[1-9]`: Match single non-zero number

`[0-9]{4}$` Last four digits can be any number between 0 and 9.